# How to get individual features from a GeoJson-Multipoint feature using map.on('click'...) in openlayers 4.6.5

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I'm trying to get the features of each MultiPoint-point when i click on a point in my openlayers map (4.6.5). The points shows on the map.

I want to add a pop-up on each feature when i click on the points in my MultiPoint array. Each individual point consists of [LON, LAT, TIME].

In have previously achieved this with a "LineString" geometry. So i wonder if this a problem with "MULTIPOINT" as geometry?

My click function looks like this:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
        var pointfeature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, vectorLayer) {

            if (feature) {
console.log(feature)
               var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
                var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));

            var geometry = feature.getGeometry(); 
            var mypoint = geometry.getClosestPoint(coordinate);
            var pointtoshow = point[1];
            content.innerHTML = '<p>feature </p>';
            overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
            }
            return feature;
        });
    });
```

My geojsonObject looks like this:

```
var geojsonObject = {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'crs': {
            'type': 'name',
            'properties': {
                'name': 'EPSG:3857'
            }
        },
        'features':[
'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'MultiPoint',
                    'coordinates': 
                        mycoordinates().map(function (x) {

                            return ol.proj.transform([x[0], x[1]], 
   'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
                        })
                    ,
                    "properties": {
                        "Time": mycoordinates().map(function (x)         
                    {
                            return x[2]
                    })
                }
            },{
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point', 
            'coordinates': ol.proj.transform([refpointlon, refpointlat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857') 
        }]
};
```

What i get from the console.log(feature) is the following:

```
Hk {Wa: {…}, qa: {…}, oa: {…}, g: 1, xp: 2, …}
N: {geometry: No}
Wa: {}
a: "geometry"
ab: {change:geometry: Array(1), change: Array(1), propertychange:         
Array(1)}
c: undefined
f: null
g: 1
i:
Ch: Hk {Wa: {…}, qa: {…}, oa: {…}, g: 1, xp: 2, …}
Dh: ƒ b(b)
Eh: false
listener: ƒ ()
target: No {Wa: {…}, qa: {…}, oa: {…}, g: 1, xp: 1, …}
type: "change"
__proto__: Object
j: undefined
oa: {change:geometry: Array(1), change: Array(1), propertychange:         
Array(1)}
qa: {}
xp: 2
__proto__: Vc
```

But this does not contain the feature coordinates, and not the feature property: TIME, as spesified in the geojsonobject.

Any suggestions for why i don't get the individual feature-information??

Comment: Try logging just the properties and the coordinates of the feature in a readable form  `console.log(JSON.stringify(feature.getProperties()));`
`console.log(JSON.stringify(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()));`

Comment: Gives the following:    Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'No'
    |     property 'ab' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'change' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     ...
    |     property 'N' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'geometry' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at test.js:439
    at h (ol.js:201)
    at ol.js:273
    at h (ol.js:263)
    at Hj (ol.js:235)
    at Ij (ol.js:236)
......

Comment: Why does it reference to the "circular structure", when it is a multipoint geometry? The multipoint is styled with Circle style, but this should not affect the getGeometry? (I am confused)